# Calling a function based on a message

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Suppose I have the following class...

```
class foo
{
    private:
        void bar(int, int);
        void bar2(int, float);
        void bar3();

        void callOne(int message);
};
```

Let's say I want to call one of those functions in `callOne()` based on the value of the `message` parameter.  Say 0 calls `bar()`, 1 calls `bar1()` and 2 calls `bar2()`.  I know the easy way out here is to use a `switch`, but in the actual implementation I feel like this may get messy as I will have many more functions.  This is basically my fall back implementation.

Is there a way using function pointers, lamdbas etc that can say, "Hey, I'm giving you this message.  Based on that message call a particular function."?  I'm basically looking for a way to look up a function (in possibly a dictionary) based on the message and call it.

Comment: Make a unordered_map with function objects

Comment: If all the functions had the same signature I would have said std::map<int, std::function<FuncSig>>. Although you might be able to do something with bind.

Comment: Just write the functions to have the same signature

Comment: @Borgleader What is bind, exactly?  Could you provide a link?

Comment: @aaronman although that is a possibility, it will add some overhead to my functions and I would like to explore other options first.

Comment: @aaronman: Why an `unordered_map`? Is the table going to be so huge that a hashtable is a reasonable idea?

Comment: @MGZero [Not entirely sure it'll be useful, but here's the doc for std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm pretty sure you can specify that the number of elems is low, also if it was me I would just use a switch, but he said no

Comment: @aaronman: And I'm pretty sure a `std::map` is easier to use and doesn't require a hash function. So why use the `unordered_map`?

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree `map` would be better

Comment: @Borgleader would you compare `bind` to function currying in haskell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to do it is with some kind of data structure that stores functions (probably as a `std::function`), which maps message names to registered functions. Whether it's a `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `boost::container::flat_map` or a map of your own design, it's going to have to be something like that.

As for the signature issue, you could simply have a fixed (small) number of signatures that you support. Internally, you store different maps, and just search each type for the appropriate function. Or you could have the map store a `boost::variant` of functions of the various parameter types, using a visitor to farm the call out to the correct type as needed.

If you need to support calling any function which takes any number of parameters, that's not generally possible. At least, not directly. For a message processing system, I typically prefer using `boost::any`. All message functions take an `any`, and the person sending a message provides one along with the message. The sender and the receiver know what the parameter is supposed to be, so the receiver can do a proper `any_cast` to convert it to the right type. And if there's a miscommunication, you get a nice exception.

Comment: The problem I have with this and the OP, is that your solution doesn't deal with the issue that the functions have different signatures, so how will you know what parameters to pass and how will the functions be stored

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, had some computer problems the last 2 days.  I'll be accepting this as the answer.